# Switch infinito en Java

Tags: java, switch

En el siguiente `código`, al ejecutar `java Menu`, si seleccionamos el **6** nos pregunta si queremos salir del `programa`, al seleccionar **Si** el programa se queda infinitamente pensando en lugar de **cerrar el programa** como es debido. El caso es que hace unas horas funcionaba correctamente con lo que no consigo ver el fallo. Adjunto el `código` por si queréis probarlo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu {
private static String file = "almacen.txt";

public static void menuManagement() {
    try {
        String menu = "1 - Ver inventario \n2 - Buscar objeto \n3 - Anhadir objeto \n4 - Retirar objeto \n5 - Eliminar objeto \n6 - Salir \n\nIntroduzca la operacion deseada";
        System.out.println(menu);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String option = scanner.next();

        switch (option) {
            case "6": //Salir
                System.out.println("Confirmar S/N");
                char exit;
                do {
                    exit = scanner.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
                    switch (exit){
                        case 's':
                            break;
                        case 'n':
                            menuManagement();
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Introduzca Si o No");
                            break;
                    }
                }while(exit != 's' || exit != 'n');
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("El termino introducido es incorrecto");
                menuManagement();
                break;
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        menuManagement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
}}
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Si ingresas 's' la condición del while no va a cumplir, antes del break debes asignarle otro valor para que salga.

Comment: No es el `switch`, es el `do ... while`. Si `exit` es `s`, `exit != 'n'` es `true`. Si `exit` es `n`, `exit != 's'` es `true`.

Comment: Además, llamar de forma recursiva al método no es la forma adecuada de responder al `n`. De hecho, cada vez que hagas `n` luego tendrás que hacer un `s` **para salir de esa llamada**, no del programa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu `case` para la opción **sí**, no hay ninguna instrucción que le indique cerrar o salir del `programa`, lo que me imagino que deberías poner dentro de ese `case` sería la siguiente instrucción: `System.exit(0)`

Quedándote como resultado:

```
case 's':
    System.exit(0);
  break;
```

De esta manera al ingresar `s`, debería cerrar tu programa.

Comment: No coloques por favor en tu respuesta el comentario respecto a que marquen o no tu respuesta como aceptada, eso lo decidirá el OP en función de que le sea útil o no